# SQLalchemy unittesting - how to pass an in memory session to a mocked session

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, mocking, python-unittest

Say I have an SQLalchemy model like:

```
from app.data_structures.base import (
    Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    flag = Column(Boolean)

    def __init__(
        self,
        user_name: str = None,
        flag: bool = false(),
)-> None:
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.flag = flag
```

where app.data_structures.base.py:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from os import environ
from os.path import join, realpath

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, scoped_session, sessionmaker


db_name = environ.get("DB_NAME")
ROOT_DIR =environ.get("ROOT_DIR")
db_path = realpath(join(ROOT_DIR, "data", db_name))
engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{db_path}", connect_args={"timeout": 120})
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sql_session = scoped_session(session_factory)


@contextmanager
def Session():
    session = sql_session()

    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise



Base = declarative_base()
```

I then have a function defined (app.helpers.db_helper.get_users_to_query), elsewhere that does something like:

```
from app.data_structures.base import Session
def get_usernames_to_query(flag: bool = False) -> List[User]:
    logger = getLogger(__name__)
    try:
        with Session() as session:
            usernames_to_query = [
                {"user_name": user.user_name}
                for user in session.query(User).filter(
                    User.flag == flag
                )
            ]
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(f"Exception thrown in get_users_to_query {' '.join(err.args)}")
        usernames_to_query = []

    return usernames_to_query
```

I am writing unittests for this app, and to try and mock out the SQLite db, and sqlalchemy I am doing the following:

```
from app.helpers.db_helper.get_users_to_query import get_users_to_query

class TestSearchUser(UserHelperTestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        return super().tearDown()
    @patch("app.data_structures.base.Session")
    def test_get_users_to_query(self, mock_session) -> None:

        self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
        self.session = Session(self.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        mock_session.return_value.__enter__.return_value = (
            self.session
        )

        (patcher, environ_dict, environ_mock_get) = self.environ_mock_get_factory()

        with patcher():

            fake_user1 = User(
                display_name="Jane Doe", user_name="jdb1", flag=False
            )
            fake_user2 = User(
                display_name="John Doe", user_name="jdb2", flag=True
            )

            with mock_session as session:
                session.add(fake_user1)
                session.add(fake_user2)
                session.commit()

                users_to_query = get_users_to_query()
                print(users_to_query)
```

But the users to query I get returned from the test are always the ones from the production DB, so the in memory db and session I set up is not being used. What is the best approach for testing this kind of set-up. I have also tried mocking the session, and setting the return values, but it didnt work.

Comment: While it would be a little bit ugly, a simple solution would be to change `app.data_structures.base.py` so that it will use an in-memory database when required (perhaps conditioning on whether `$DB_NAME` is defined?). Then you don't have bother with passing mocked sessions around.

Comment: what exactly do you want to `mock`? `session.query(User).filter()` method?

Comment: I want to mock the return from the query().filter call, or the entire session if that makes more sense @DanilaGanchar.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `query` + `filter()`. Here is an example:

> pip install sqlalchemy==2.0.20

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from unittest.mock import Mock

from sqlalchemy import String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, DeclarativeBase, Session
from sqlalchemy.orm._orm_constructors import mapped_column

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_account'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))


with Session(engine) as session:
    # create a user for demo
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session.add_all([User(name='super sonic')])
    session.commit()


class TestExample(TestCase):
    def test_without_mock(self):
        # check if the user exists
        with Session(engine) as session:
            users = list(session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'super sonic'))
            self.assertEqual(len(users), 1)

    def test_mock(self):
        with mock.patch(
            'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.query',
            # mock session.query
            return_value=Mock(
                # mock filter()
                filter=Mock(
                    side_effect=(
                        [User(name='mock1'), User(name='mock2')],  # result of first filter() call
                        [User(name='mock3'), User(name='mock4')],  # result of second filter() call
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ):
            self.assertListEqual(
                [
                    dict(name='mock1'),
                    dict(name='mock2'),
                ],
                [
                    dict(name=u.name) for u in
                    session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'super sonic')
                ]
            )

            self.assertListEqual(
                [
                    dict(name='mock3'),
                    dict(name='mock4'),
                ],
                [
                    dict(name=u.name) for u in
                    session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'super sonic')
                ]
            )
```

Run `pytest {YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME}.py`:

```
=========================================================== test session starts ============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /home/{PATH_TO_PROJECT}
plugins: anyio-3.7.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                          

{YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME}.py ..                                                                                                                          [100%]

============================================================ 2 passed in 0.19s =============================================================
```